# What is the most efficient logic to check for all possible combinations of three flags?

Tags: if-statement, switch-statement, logic, control-flow

I have three flags which may be True or False. I need to display an icon for each possible combination of flags. Since there are three flags that means, in combination, there are eight possible states. (Shown below, where **bold** represents true.)

A   B   C

**A**   B   C

A   **B** C

A   B   **C**

**A   B**   C

**A**   B   **C**

A   **B  C**

**A  B  C**

Is there an advantageous control flow to use in checking the flags to minimize unnecessary checking? (Would this vary by which flags are *likely* to be on or off?)

---

**Edit:**

For example, when I was looking at simply flags A and B, my control flow was -

```
if(A & B) 
{
    // Display icon for A+B 
}
else if (A) 
{
    // Display icon for A 
} 
else if (B)
{
    // Display icon for B 
}
```

Comment: (If there is a problem with this question please let me know and I will strive to improve it.)

Answer (score 2):

I would set up an 8 bit variable, allowing bits 2,1,0 to store your flag states.

Then

```
switch(variablename)
{
  case 0:

  break;

  ..
  ..

  case 7:

  break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void grdDemo_ItemDataBound(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (!(e.Item is GridDataItem) || (e.Item.DataItem == null))
    {
        return;
    }

    ///////////////////
    //// Solution 1 ///
    ///////////////////

    // If it is possible to manipulate image name
    MyClass M1 = e.Item.DataItem as MyClass;
    ImageButton imgStatus = (ImageButton)e.Item.FindControl("imgStatus");

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    sb.Append(M1.A ? "1" : "0");
    sb.Append(M1.B ? "1" : "0");
    sb.Append(M1.C ? "1" : "0");

    string ImageName = "imgStaus" + sb.ToString() + ".jpg";
    imgStatus.ImageUrl = "~/path/" + ImageName;


    ///////////////////
    //// Solution 2 ///
    ///////////////////

    ImageName = string.Empty;

    double FlagCount = 0;
    FlagCount += Math.Pow((M1.A ? 0 : 1) * 2, 3);
    FlagCount += Math.Pow((M1.B ? 0 : 1) * 2, 2);
    FlagCount += Math.Pow((M1.B ? 0 : 1) * 2, 1);
    var intFlagCount = (int)FlagCount;

    switch (intFlagCount)
    {
        case 0:
            ImageName = "imgStausFFF.jpg";
            break;
        case 1:
            ImageName = "imgStausFFT.jpg";
            break;
        case 2:
            ImageName = "imgStausFTF.jpg";
            break;
        case 3:
            ImageName = "imgStausFTT.jpg";
            break;
        case 4:
            ImageName = "imgStausTFF.jpg";
            break;
        case 5:
            ImageName = "imgStausTFT.jpg";
            break;
        case 6:
            ImageName = "imgStausTTF.jpg";
            break;
        case 7:
            ImageName = "imgStausTTT.jpg";
            break;
    }

    imgStatus.ImageUrl = "~/path/" + ImageName;

    //////DONE!!!!!!!!!!

}

class MyClass
{
    public bool A { get; set; }
    public bool B { get; set; }
    public bool C { get; set; }
}
```